# jQuery nested within .get request won't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery `get` request, which returns html text under the key name "data":

```
$(".article").click(function() {
  $.get("<%= click_path %>", function(data) {
    $(".article").html(data);
  });
});
```

All the code executes except the line `$(".article").html(data);`. In fact, any jquery code I put inside the `get` request fails to execute, even though it all works fine if I move it outside the `get` request. Does anyone see anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Is your scriplet returning the right values ? @Joe Morano

Comment: Are you using Ruby or ASP.net for your server-side scripting?  If you inspect the output in the Chrome Console or Firebug, is <%= click_path %> replaced with the expected URL?

Comment: check whether it is going inside by using console or alert. there may be possible going in error callback as asked by @dipole_moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method is an alias to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with an assumed HTTP request method of `GET` and without the ability to specify many options. You give it a URL and a function to run on successfully retrieving that URL. It tries to `GET` that URL and, *if* it can, the success function will run. If it can't, or if something is wrong with the response data, it fails silently and will *not* run the given function.

That being the case, I would assume your request is failing somewhere.

You need to look in the developer's console for errors and to inspect the request.

You can also change your code to use `$.ajax` and pass in the options, along with your current params, an `error` method. If the `error` method is called, you'll receive as params the `jqXHR` instance, a string `textStatus`, and a string `errorThrown`. Pass these into `console.log` and look at them for clues as to what is wrong as well.

```
$(".article").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= click_path %>",
        success: function(data) {
            $(".article").html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, your ajax request fails to execute and as result, your jQuery code inside the callback never runs.

Run the following instead and see if an error is alerted:

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "<%= click_path %>", function() {
  alert( "success" );
}
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```